# C# while (!process.HasExited)

Tags: c#

Hey I got a simple question I use the following code:

```
while (!process.HasExited) 
{ 
mycode 
}
```

how safe is this? What if the user shutdown his pc or restart. Will this code fail? if it's in the process of shutting down this while equal true? (Process.hasExited)

Thanks!

Comment: Needs much more detail. Like what process, what's in `mycode` etc.

Comment: There is [an API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376877.aspx) you can use at the start of `mycode` to prevent Windows shutting down, but it's always going to be a bit of a race. I'd think you'd get enough cycles to register the lock though.

Comment: we can guess the process is a variable of type `Process`

Comment: @Henk I'd guess the question is "I want to reliably run a block of code after my child process has exited. How can I guarantee this happens even when the processes are terminated by Windows shutting down or restarting?"

Comment: what is the purpose of thise code?

Comment: Processes can be killed, always assume nothing was done upon termination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you restart your computer, it tidies up all running processes so your application won't even be running.

As to how safe it is, its got its weaknesses your program will be in limbo until it manages to assess that the program has exited.

`process.WaitForExit()` or `process.WaitForExit(10000)` may be better alternatives

Comment: thanks a lot for your help always very helpful! this means I can use it. What worried me that the code can make the wrong decision if it's starting to shut down...

Comment: No worries, You may find a book on the fundamentals of how a computer works an interesting read :) Warning you will find it boring at first but apparently it sinks in!